# Python 'colour' and 'colour-science' module conflict

Tags: python-3.x, colors, pip, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to convert some spectral data to XYZ with colour-science module. However, none of the methods or module data is available after import colour. I've read that the issue with the same namespace with the 'colour' module, but found no working solution for me.
I've tried installing it with pip3 and via git link on my computer.

```
pip install colour-science
pip3 install colour-science
pip3 install git+https://github.com/crowsonkb/colour@JMh
```

Is there a possible way to specifically import the 'colour-science' module or prioritize it somehow?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the module names are the same, just `import colour as something_else`

**EDIT:** you will need to unintsall `colour` (and reinstall `colour-science`), because `colour` is a fork of `colour-science`, so pip uninstalls it.

Comment: Thank you! It helped a lot after running it in another notebook as well with no saved data, I suppose.

Comment: This may satisfy the OP, but what if the conflict comes from two underlying libraries, one of which requires `colour` and the other which requires `colour-science`?  I added [issue #958](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/issues/958).